# Split strings in arrays to more arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have this array:

```
["Name: Bob, LastName: Smith, Age: 77","Name: John, LastName: Cabbage, Age: 34","Name: Regan, LastName: Gobsmolly, Age: 80"]
```

How would you split all the strings in the array into more arrays from the comma, so the result would end up like this:

```
[["Name: Bob", "LastName: Smith", "Age: 77"],["Name: John", "LastName: Cabbage", "Age: 34"],["Name: Regan", "LastName: Gobsmolly", "Age: 80"]]
```

I have already tried splitting the items in the array with a loop, with the aim of returning the `Name` value from every array:

```
function getEntryNames(nameSplit) {
        var nameSplit;
        for (var i = 0; i < nameSplit.length; i++) {
            return nameSplit[i].split(',')[i];
        }
    }
document.write(getEntryNames(theArray))
```

The problem is, the function will only split the first item in the array, so I get this result:

```
Name: Bob
```

When I really want this result:

```
Name: Bob, Name: John, Name: Regan
```

So how do you split items in an array to more arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:
(the original array content will be replaced in the process)

```
var arr = ["Name: Bob, LastName: Smith, Age: 77","Name: John, LastName: Cabbage, Age: 34","Name: Regan, LastName: Gobsmolly, Age: 80"];

function splitSomething(arr) {
  var item;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      item = arr[i];
      arr[i] = item.split(',');
    }
  return arr;
}
console.log(splitSomething(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply execute `split()` to every item of an array using `Array.prototype.map`:

```js
var arr = ["Name: Bob, LastName: Smith, Age: 77","Name: John, LastName: Cabbage, Age: 34","Name: Regan, LastName: Gobsmolly, Age: 80"];

arr = arr.map(function(x) { 
    return x.split(',').map(function(x) { return x.trim(); });
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr); // just an output
```

`String.prototype.trim` is simply supposed to remove leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about map() (I am relatively new to javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your array name is `arr`:

```
arr.map(function (e) { return e.split(", "); })
```

I tested this code in nodejs console, and the result is:

```
> var arr = ["Name: Bob, LastName: Smith, Age: 77","Name: John, LastName: Cabbage, Age: 34","Name: Regan, LastName: Gobsmolly, Age: 80"]
undefined
> arr.map(function (e) { return e.split(", "); })
[ [ 'Name: Bob', 'LastName: Smith', 'Age: 77' ],
  [ 'Name: John', 'LastName: Cabbage', 'Age: 34' ],
  [ 'Name: Regan', 'LastName: Gobsmolly', 'Age: 80' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` can do this easily :

```
arr.map(function(str) {
    return str.split(',');
});
```

You may have to trim some strings to have the good result :

```
arr.map(function(str) {
    return str.split(',').map(function(val) {
        return val.trim();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this. Because you put return so the function after the first element.

```
function getData(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i];
    var item = {};
    var array = value.split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      var element = array[j].split(":");
      var key = element[0].trim();
      var value = element[1].trim();
      item[key] = value;
    }
    result.push(item);
  }
  return result;
}
```